# Return custom value for row in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have my model :

```
const User = sequelize.define(
'User',
{
  user_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
    allowNull: false,
  },
},
{
  tableName: 'user',
  getterMethods: {
    shortDescription: function(size)  {
      return this.description.substring(0, size);
    },
  },
}
);
```

I added `shortDescription` as an example of what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to use it. I want *ALL* my queries to return a modified description.

```
const users = await User.findAndCountAll({
  limit,
  offset,
  attributes: {
    include: [[Sequelize.fn('LEFT', Sequelize.col('description'), myLength), 'description']],
  },
});
```

Here I'm achieving the same goal with a custom function, but assuming I have multiple functions and subqueries, I feel like re-writing the include clause is a bit inefficient. Ultimately, if a `myLength` is specified, I want the description to be trimmed, otherwise, have a default value set in the model that trims it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Model expansion](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#expansion-of-models).

After your model's code, I believe you could write something like :

```
User.Instance.prototype.getShortDescription = function(length) {
  return this.description.substring(0, length);
}
```

Comment: how would I use this function inside a query to set the length of the description? basically how would i force this function to be called every time i select from my table?

Comment: I'm not sure such a thing exists, sadly.